# Prevent root web.config to be overriden by a sub web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have 2 web.config files at root/ and at root/Web. I want that when I hit /Root/Web my application should load a certain set of settings from the root/Web.Config even though they are present in /root/web/Web.config

Any ideas where and what should I be modifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way to do that is removing the elements in sub web.config that conflict with the settings in the root web.config.

If you need them for other purposes then you need to read whatever settings you want/need and apply them programmatically.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx):

> The root of the ASP.NET configuration hierarchy is a file referred to
>   as the root Web.config file, and it is located in the same directory
>   as the Machine.config file. The root Web.config file inherits all of
>   the settings in the Machine.config file. The root Web.config file
>   includes settings that apply to all of the ASP.NET applications that
>   run a specific version of the .NET Framework. **Because each ASP.NET
>   application inherits default configuration settings from the root
>   Web.config file, you need to create Web.config files only for settings
>   that override the default settings**.

Comment: Basically I don't have an option of modifying the sub web.config file. I want the app to use the config settings in the root web.config even though the sub web.config has the same settings in itself.